# Where to download Sql Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to do a fresh install in a lab environment. Where's a good place to download it?

Comment: I'd look on Microsoft's website.

Comment: Why use ancient 2008R2 ?

Comment: @kin, to get off of ancient 2008R2. Before I just run the wizard and hope for the best, I want to do it on a lab server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it for a lab environment you can get a preconfigured VHD with an evaluation edition of 2008 R2 installed. It is valid for 180 days:

[SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 Standard (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26113)

Also, you can get it if you or one of your colleagues have a MSDN subscription. If the subscription is not yours you can download it from there and use it for the 180 day evaluation period.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite link for SQL server verisons is
https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/
It shows the current versions and links to the install files.

Comment: How does this answers the question ? That link is for builds - CU and service packs.

Comment: That site has links to all of the builds, SPs and CUs for SQL Server.  Including 2008 R2.

Comment: Links are broken for 2008 r2.